# How can I refactor this for loop to adhere to the DRY principle?

Tags: python, dry

How can I retain the functionality of the code below without repeating the commented lines?

```
def my_round(number, place=10):
    digit_list = [digit for digit in str(number)]
    rounded_number = ''
    round_list = [10 ** i for i in range(10)]
    zeros = str(place).count('0')

    for i in round_list:
        if (place == i):
            if int(digit_list[-zeros]) >= 5:
                for x in range(-zeros, 0):                # <- These 
                    digit_list[x] = '0'                   # <-
                rounded_number = int(''.join(digit_list)) # <-
                rounded_number += i
            else:
                for x in range(-zeros, 0):                # <- Repeat...
                    digit_list[x] = '0'                   # <-
                rounded_number = int(''.join(digit_list)) # <-

    return rounded_number

print(my_round(56, 10))
```

I'm new to Python and programming in general. This is also my first question on Stackoverflow but don't hesitate to tell me where I can do better in either asking questions or coding in Python!

I'm eager to learn!

Comment: This may be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, Alex! I didn't know this existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general way to remove duplication is to define a function. This can even be done inside another function:

```
def my_round(number, place=10):
    digit_list = [digit for digit in str(number)]
    rounded_number = ''
    round_list = [10 ** i for i in range(10)]
    zeros = str(place).count('0')

    def round_inner():
        for x in range(-zeros, 0):
            digit_list[x] = '0'
        return int(''.join(digit_list))

    for i in round_list:
        if (place == i):
            if int(digit_list[-zeros]) >= 5:
                rounded_number = round_inner()
                rounded_number += i
            else:
                rounded_number = round_inner()

    return rounded_number
```

In your case, there's a simpler way:

```
def my_round(number, place=10):
    digit_list = [digit for digit in str(number)]
    rounded_number = ''
    round_list = [10 ** i for i in range(10)]
    zeros = str(place).count('0')

    for i in round_list:
        if (place == i):
            round_up = int(digit_list[-zeros]) >= 5
            for x in range(-zeros, 0):
                digit_list[x] = '0'
            rounded_number = int(''.join(digit_list))

            if round_up:
                rounded_number += i

    return rounded_number
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your example is convoluted on purpose, but if not you could replace it all with:

```
def my_round(number, place=10):
    return int(round(float(number) / place) * place)
```

Comment: Thanks neurotik! I was attempting to emulate the round() function without actually using it, so I suppose it did get convoluted. In the real world, your code would be better suited.